# Is it possible to move up/down and/or arrange the conversations in Skype `Recent` tab?

Tags: conversion, skype

At the moment, the list is sorted by the time+date of first message of the conversation only - later on when I get many conversations of the day, the most recent message of an old conversation lies deep down in the list - which is NOT very convenient to me.

I want to re-order my conversations in `Recent` tab. Is it possible? If it is, please show me how to. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's possible.